# JMeter never fails

Tags: multithreading, jmeter

I'm trying to stress test a server with JMeter. I followed the manual and successfully created the tests (Test are running ok and response is correct).

However even if I keep increasing the number of threads it never fails, but I keep reading that there must be limitations? So what am I doing wrong?

My CPU is running on +/-5% when I'm not running JMeter. Running 3000 threads I see the number of threads increase by 3000 and CPU usage goes to +/-15%. Also JMeter never complains something went wrong.

My JMeter configuration is:
Number of threads: 3000
Ramp-Up Period: 30
LoopCount: Forever (Let it run for over an hour and still nothing goes wrong)

The bottleneck now is my internet connection which simply can't handle this load and maxes out at 2.1Mbps. Is this causing the problem? It is increasing my latency from 10ms per thread to over 5000ms per thread, but threads are still running.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have confirmed that you definitely aren't getting back any errors (e.g. using a results table listener, or logging/displaying only errors using a results graph listener) and your internet connection is running at capacity then yes, it does sound like your internet connection is the bottleneck.  It doesn't sound like your server is being stressed at all.

If you can easily make use of other machines (e.g. servers in the same location as the server you are testing), you could try using JMeter remote (distributed) testing to sidestep the limitations of your internet connection.  See http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html for details.

Alternatively, if it's easy (e.g. if you're using VM's in a cloud and can easily spin one up with your software on), you could try using the least-powerful server you can instead and stress testing that to see if you can make it struggle even with your internet connection (just as a sanity check).

If this doesn't help, more details on your server (hardware specifications, web server software and thread pool settings, language) and the site/pages you are testing (mostly static or dynamic? large requests/responses?) would be useful.  I've certainly managed to make lower-powered machines (e.g. EC2 m1.small) struggle using JMeter over a 2Mbps connection, but it depends on the site you're testing.

Comment: I im using the listener -> view results three to view the output. But even with the 2Mbps internet the server is still beiing called by the threads right? But because of the big latency it isn't a correct stress test because tests are simply waiting for a response? Is this correct? I think i can also try to create a local network between the server and laptop to increase the bandwidth.

Comment: Yes, the server should still be being called, but it's probably not managing 3000 parallel requests.  Also, you're limited by the power of your laptop.  How is its performance and how does its CPU/RAM look when you try to run 3000 threads?  I've never tried that many from a single laptop.  Are you sure your network is the bottleneck and not your laptop CPU/RAM?  Just to confirm, your server is at a remote location and the tests are running on your laptop, right?  If so, I don't see any way that creating a 'local network' would help - everything has to go over your internet connection anyway.

Comment: No the server is "intern". So i can just add a wired connection to a router and then to my laptop. This way i should be able to reach 100Mbps. The test are indeed running on my laptop. Creating 2 threads makes the internet go to 1.9Mbps and CPU to approx 20%. Creating up to 3000 threads limits the internet to 2.1Mbps but CPU stays the same. However the number of threads on the CPU do increase. So looks to me like the internet just limits the threads, but they are infact running.

Comment: Strange if the packets go externally just to come back to your local network, but perhaps it depends on routing details. In that case, they'd go outside your router even if you have a wired connection between the machines and the router so you'd still be limited. Perhaps try the local IP of the server so the packets shouldn't go outside your router? Then you should be limited to the speed of your wireless instead of your internet connection. Then adding a wired connection might increase speed. Either way you will probably rapidly reach your laptop's limits if you have 20% CPU with 2 threads!