# Apache benchmark failed request on Connect?

Tags: apache, jmeter, apachebench

Im trying to stress test my server. I started using JMeter but this did did not work like i wished. Im trying the same with apache benchmark but run on a failed request i just dont know what it means.

I tried stressing it with:

`ab -n 10000 -c 2000` and works like a charm (Atleast zero errors)

`ab -b 20000 -c 5000` worked most of the times but got one time the following result:

> Completed requests:  20000
>   Failed requests:     7
>       (Connect: 7, Receive: 0, Length: 0, Exceptions: 0)

So what does this Connect error mean?
Tried it again few minuts later and got 0 failed request..

Turns out running `ab -n 40000 -c 10000` is not working because xampp crashes.

Also, is it true that my server has to fail at some point? Or is it just good it aint crashing.

As we speak i am running over 1500 threads with JMeter for more than 2 hours now, nothing goes wrong so far..

Answer (score 0):

Take particilar attention to -c in ab its equivalent is the number of threads in JMeter provided your script in JMeter is very basic (one same request).

If this works fine:

- ab -n 10000 -c 2000

It is fine that a jmeter script with 1500 threadq works fine, a JMeter equivalent to the above ab command is 2000 threads with loop count to 5

Also it is regular that the more you increase -c the more your server faces errors.

Also once you have a high number of threads in JMeter ensure you follow best-practices.

Finally ab is more for basic load simulation, jmeter for realistic and complex navigation scenarios.

Comment: The reason i started using ab instead of JMeter was the fact that while using JMeter my CPU did not "overload". Creating 5 threads and running them forever means like 20% CPU, creating 100 threads and running them forever same (20% CPU). Using ab i was able to increase my CPU by upping the number of threads. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23286276/jmeter-never-fails

Comment: Your issue is definitely strange, are you using jmeter or ab on same machine as target server ? I don't think so. What are you testing with ab vs jmeter ? is it the same thing ? Can you share your Test Plan or show a screenshot of it ?